# Preserve browser window aspect ratio while shrinking

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="spacer--1200x800.png" width="1200" height="800" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is CSS code

```
body {
    background-image: url('b2.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Please check the code above. When shrinking the web browser, the image is resizing properly, but I need the window height to resize at the same time as the image resizes. I don't need that blank white space, so if the width is resized, I need the height to  automatically resize, just like that image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is filled with grammatical errors that prevent us from understanding what you're asking. I don't see a clear question here; what exactly do you want?

Comment: After editing it is a completely valid question. To attempt to resize the actual browser window may not be a good idea or even possible, but the question is valid and a new SO user does not need to be so heavily downvoted or have his question closed

Comment: possible duplicate of [need help plz check the sample code here i pasted and need solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169579/need-help-plz-check-the-sample-code-here-i-pasted-and-need-solution)

Comment: guys.. first i want to say sorry.. see im not gud in english lik u and all.. its jus a language to communicate.. i think this web site is not a english grammar test website.. am i right..? its a forum abt technical.. if any wrong on user's question jus ask them til u understand.. no one is perfect in their communication.. sorry if u tak my words as wrong.. i hate this forum... jus change this website name "STACK OVERFLOW" to "ENGLISH RULING HERE".. and and if anybody open this is site ju warn them "its only for gud in english people" okie... gud bye guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a good idea. Resizing the window is frowned upon, and in recent browser versions it's rarely allowed. See [these notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.resizeTo#Notes) about the rules that Firefox imposes.

However, it would be possible, if you are allowed to resize the window, to call `window.resizeTo` with the right parameters computed using `window.innerWidth`, `window.innerHeight`, `window.outerWidth`, `window.outerHeight`.

Something like this should work:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    var targetInnerHeight = window.innerWidth * 800 / 1200;
    var heightDiff = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;
    var targetOuterHeight = targetInnerHeight + heightDiff;
    window.resizeTo(window.outerWidth, targetOuterHeight);
}
```

But again, **you shouldn't do this**, in most cases the browser won't let you do that for security reasons, and it's not nice to manipulate the user's browser and prevent the user from resizing the browser as he pleases.